# AnkhSVN trouble : "please select a valid location in the repository to add to"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I've tried to solve this error message but I couldn't.

I've tried for a really long time, I just can't figure a solution to this.

I'm using Ankh plugin with Visual Studio 2010, I've got an SVN repository on unfuddle.com and I'm trying to import my project into that new repository.

this is the error message I get :

" please select a valid location in the repository to add to"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually got to the source of the problem. It was due to the fact that I access the SVN repository from behind a proxy server.

Answer (score 2):

The path to my subversion URL was file:///fileserver/etc/SVNTutorial#1.
It appears that AnkhSVN does not like # characters in the URL path. 
When I removed the # character it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

attention: you have to create the repository first in the unfuddle admin menu!!!! this repo you have create has an url, this is the url where you can check in you project!

Comment: i've already created the repository in unfuddle. and now, i'm trying to import my project's files into it.

Comment: ok then you sould do: svn import /yourparh/to/files http...../prjecturl - after this you MUST!! checkout the project again!!! to another directory. from this one you can work now

Comment: I actually got to the source of the problem. It was due to the fact that I access the SVN repository from behind a proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

Does the [help](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/dialogs/Ankh.UI.SccManagement.AddToSubversion) for this dialog contain a solution for your problem? You can access this help by hitting the `?` button in the dialog.

Comment: I actually got to the source of the problem. It was due to the fact that I access the SVN repository from behind a proxy server.